# How to convert 24hr to 12hr in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, date

I am using API for getting time but the time is coming in 24hr. I want to convert to 12hr.

Need a code example for this

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateFormat`(from `package:intl/intl.dart`) to display in 12hr format.

```dart
DateFormat('h:mm a').format(DateTime.now());
```

Comment: how to use in this  Text(snapshot.data.data.timings.dhuhr),

Comment: You should be able to parse your `dhuhr` as a `DateTime` and pass it: `Text(DateFormat('h:mm a').format(DateTime.parse(snapshot.data.timings.dhuhr)))`. Though I guess you may want to first ensure that the snapshot contains a valid DateTime.

Comment: Invalid date format
05:28 it give this error

Comment: Add sample data for `snapshot.data.timings.dhuhr`